# Rotation and radial translation together in a group?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, geometry

Being a happy beginner in algebra and groups, i would like to build a group that can systematically represent (in 2 dimensions):

1. Rotation around origin.
2. Translation along radius.

I have learned that complex numbers can represent rotation with some resolution $\theta$ : $$\bf M_{R(\theta)} = \begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}, \cases{a=\cos(\theta)\\b=\sin(\theta)}$$

And then translation with a resolution $k$ : $$\bf M_{T(k)}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\k&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Can I combine these somehow to achieve what I want? To build a general matrix with help of these matrices and their exponents $${\bf M(\theta,k)} = f({\bf M_{T(k)},M_{R(\theta)}},e_\theta,e_k)$$

---

**Edit : An image to try and clarify :** We want our group to take a given line to any other given line, we measure their distance to origo and their angle. The point of interest ( which i am talking about above ) will have a $\Delta$ in each of the dimensions: angle $\theta$ and radius translation $k$.

[image]

Example where the blue line is taken to the black line by concatenating the operations: $$\cases{r = r - 0\cdot 0.125\\\theta =\theta+ 2\cdot \frac{\pi}{8}}$$
The other tuples decide the numbers for lines of the other colors. We want to find a matrix representation of generators for a group which does this. The red helper circles are centered on origo and of radiuses $0.25,0.5$ to help see what the "translation" operation is supposed to do.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "translation along the radius" or "translation with resolution $k$"... Your matrix $\bf M_{T(k)}$ does not define a translation on $\Bbb R^2$, in fact no matrix defines a translation as translations are not linear.

Comment: It is only intended as a 1D translation in the radial direction ${\bf M_{T(k)}}^n = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\kn&1 \end{bmatrix}$ is $n$ "steps" if k is 1 "step". The length in position $(2,1)$ of the matrix. And the inverses are intended to correspond to steps in opposite direction.

Comment: But it's not a translation, since it fixes the origin...

Comment: Yes, but it is not a scaling either. I don't know the word for it. I want to traverse back and forth radially on a linear scale and let the rotation steer the angle.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if you have a point $P$, you want to map it to a point $Q$ that is on the same line through the origin $O$, and such that $d(O,Q)=k\cdot d(O,P)$? Or do you want something like $d(O,Q)=d(O,P)+k$?

Comment: You are right, my formulation probably makes no sense they way I wrote it. What I mean is to take a line, shift the closest distance to origo by $kn$, then rotate around origo. The line will be preserved a line, but will have a difference in angle to closest point by $\theta m$ and closest closeness to origo by $kn$. I will try make a picture to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that we start with closest point at the x-axis, one way to calculate the **group action** on a point $(x,y) \in {\mathbb R}^2$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}\underset{\text{Rotation generator}}{\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}a&-b&0\\b&a&0\\0&0&0\\\end{bmatrix}}}^{\,\,m}\underset{\text{Translation generator}}{\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}1&0&k\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}}}^n\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

Or in vector form with $\bf V$ having columns being **points to act on** and $\bf t$ being a translation vector:

$$\begin{bmatrix}\bf I_2&\bf 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\bf R&\bf 0\\{\bf 0}^T&0\\\end{bmatrix}^m\begin{bmatrix}{\bf I_2}&\bf t\\\bf 0&1\end{bmatrix}^n\begin{bmatrix}\bf V\\{\bf 1}^T\end{bmatrix}$$

The lines above were generated using this recipe, so it has been verified to work.

An illustration for comparision to the [fan beam scan](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2166752/213607) we here instead imagine tangential tracks on a circular rail shooting parallell rays for each rotation of the gun, translation corresponds to relocating along the track, rotation is relocating along the circle:
[image]