# Generating a fan beam sweep algebraically.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, geometry, finite-groups, representation-theory

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2149901/rotation-and-radial-translation-together-in-a-group/2151243#2151243), I wondered about if the same functionality is possible to achieve with a fan-beam sweep, where instead of translation we have a second rotation (around some point). Like this:

[image]

I would like one generating element for aim of the ray (same color) and another to rotate the raygun (new color), and of course a description of how to put it all together for a matrix representation and group-action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this, which is in the same spirit as [previous question on group for combining translation and rotation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2149901/rotation-and-radial-translation-together-in-a-group?noredirect=1&lq=1). In octave, having defined two $2 \times 2$ rotation matrices $\bf R_1,R_2$:

$${\bf R_1} = \begin{bmatrix}a_1&-b_1\\b_1&a_1\end{bmatrix}\hspace{1cm} {\bf R_2} = \begin{bmatrix}a_2&-b_2\\b_2&a_2\end{bmatrix}$$

And a translation matrix, $\bf T$ and it's inverse ${\bf T_i = T}^{-1}$:

$${\bf T} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&k\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\hspace{1cm} {\bf T_i} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&-k\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
Then the GNU Octave / Mathworks Matlab function:

```
  f = @(k1,k2) [R1^k1,[0;0];0,0,1]*T*[R2^k2,[0;0];0,0,1]*Ti;
```

generates a that rotates a line from $\cases{x \in [0,1]\\ y=0}$ $k_1$ and $k_2$ ticks respectively.

Working on a column vector, separating and explaining the steps:

1. $k=1$ makes $\bf T_i$ move whole plane 1 unit left ( decrease x by one ).
2. Now line has other end in origo, which is a preparation for the $\bf R_2$ matrix to rotate correctly.
3. After the rotation, $\bf T$ moves 1 x-coordinate so rightmost point ends up on $[1,0]$ once again.
4. $\bf R_1$ performs the last rotation which moves [1,0] to a new position ( on the unit circle ).